# sql database collation mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I am trying to query two separate databases using one script.
However, both databases have different collations. I have tried to force the collation to change by running a script like this:

```
use master
go
alter database database1
collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
go
```

This does run but then it makes no difference when I try to run this query (even though both databases are now using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS):

```
select [Manufacturer],[ModelNumber] from database1.dbo.CVStore_Products inner join database2.dbo.tProduct on [StoreProductCode]=[ModelNumber]
```

What am I doing wrong? Because I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

Thanks for your help in advance! :D

Comment: People can't help you if you don't specify what database engine you're using.

Comment: Yeah.  Last time I had a collation issue I uninstalled and reinstalled SQL with the right collation, then reimported all of my data.  True story.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008.Ok,maybe a re-install might be the way to go.

Comment: Ok, this might help you.  http://memegenerator.net/instance/30964908

Comment: Resolved.Dropped the database and rebuilt it.Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Collation can be a pain. But is has been around for quite a while.
Here's [a post from Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/), dating from 2007.
It has examples to either correct the collation in the query directly or to alter the collation for a specific column.

Changing the collation setting for an entire database, does not affect existing columns, as far as I can recall.
Any new columns will use the new setting.

Comment: Hi Jacco,I think you're right.I have checked the collation of the individual columns and they are different to the database collation.Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

OP note says he dropped the database.

Note to future users:

Options:

1. Update tSQL query
2. Update collation column in table
3. Update collation of database
4. Update collation of SQLServer master database

**Update tSQL query****

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'casesearch'
```

**Update collation column in table**

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN Column1 VARCHAR(20)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

**Update collation of database**

[SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-ver15) say:

```
USE master;  
GO

ALTER DATABASE MyOptionsTest  
    COLLATE French_CI_AS ;  
GO  
  
SELECT name, collation_name  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE name = N'MyOptionsTest';  
GO
```

**Update collation of SQLServer master database**

[SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation?view=sql-server-ver15) say:

1. Export all your data
2. Drop all the user databases.
3. Rebuild the master database specifying the new collation in the SQLCOLLATION property of the setup command. For example:

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[ SAPWD= StrongPassword ]
/SQLCOLLATION=CollationName
```

Warning:

> When the master, model, msdb, and tempdb system databases are rebuilt
> [MS Docs: Rebuild System Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)